# Query database through Excel VBA

Tags: database, excel, teradata, vba

I am a beginner in Excel VBA. I want to query data from Teradata database and give the output into the rows of an excel sheet. When i write the below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim conn As Connection
    Dim rec1 As Recordset
    Dim thisSql As String
    Set conn = New Connection
    conn.Open "Driver=Teradata; DBCName=" & DBCName & ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD
    thisSql = "simple select qyery here"
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=conn, Destination:=.Range("A1"))
        .Sql = thisSql
        .Name = "data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I am getting the error saying **'Compiler error: User-defined type not defined'**

how to overcome this error? Do i need to include anything in the code?

Please help

I am using MSVisualBasic 6.5 editor

Comment: showing the error at the line: Dim conn As Connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I guess it would need a recordset as the connection object when using QueryTables.Add. 
I modified your code and tried it as following:

```
Dim conn As adodb.Connection
Dim rec1 As adodb.Recordset
Dim thisSql As String

Set conn = New adodb.Connection

conn.Open your_connection_string

thisSql = "your query here"

Set rec1 = New adodb.Recordset
rec1.Open thisSql, conn

With Sheet3.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=Sheet3.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Hi Jim... Thanks for the reply... I have changed the code...but im still facing the same error.. My code is not identifying 'Connection' as a keyword... I feel

Comment: Strange~ Did you check the reference to Microsoft ActiveX data Objects library on your project? I tested the above the code and succeeded.

Comment: Thank you Jim.. tat suggestion helped. I've checkd the ActiveX lib in the reference for the project.
I have a question here: Actually i first tried to check activeX, i was unable to see it.Then I opened other VBAProject which I know & is working fine(with database) and it was having the ActiveX checked..then I was able to check the ActiveX ref for my project also.

Comment: This is in continuation with the above comment:
So,if I uncheck ActiveX lib for my prjct and i want to check it again.then Iam unable to see the ActiveX lib in the references ..in this case I need to open other project and then Check ActiveX reference in my project and i am saving it.
any help on how to include references if there are not available in the lit box of the references?

Comment: checking the library beforehand is called 'early binding'. when you open the reference dialog box, it shows the checked libs on the top. I guess you might have had difficulty finding the proper lib. beside the early binding, there is late-binding. you should use CreateObject function for late-binding. for more info, plz google it and you can find tons of pages on the web.

Comment: The words 'Early binding' and 'Late binding' will help me to dig more. Thank you.